# how to call webservice using Ajax with jquery?

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-services, jquery

I'm using the following code to call the webservice by using jQuery ajax. But It doesn't work? The webservice return the value in JSON format. How can I access the webservice through this code?

```
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input[id^="button"]').click(function () {
            alert('You have clicked ' + $(this).val());
            $.ajax({
                type: 'Get',
                url: 'http://localhost:56789/xxx/Handler.ashx?key=yyy ',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });

        })
    })
    </script>

     <body>
        <div id="Sample_Div">
            <input type="button" id="button1" value="button1" />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works for me. What error do you get?

Comment: Am not getting any error at the same time am not getting result

Comment: What does the Javascript Console say?

Comment: Add type="text/javascript" to the script tag to get rid of that warning. Add the code for Handler.ashx.  Is the request getting to your handler or is the handler not returning a valid response.

Comment: Handler give the response but I use the same URL in ajax i didn't get the value

Comment: @binarious How the hell does this work for you? I'm not trolling, just really curious. Did you implement a service to listen to your localhost's 56789 port and also implemented a fake response?

Comment: @binarious wow I'm speechless. Care to share your server side code? Maybe it'll bring us one step closer to help "user".

Comment: @AndrásSzepesházi It doesn't metter what implementation you have. You could run for instance a php server on that port and echo out 'test'.

Comment: This is potentially down to a cross-domain issue, if the ports are different on localhost.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try this one.

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "../Services/Person.asmx/SavePersonById",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        data: '{ID:"00123"}',
        success: function (response) {
            //do whatever your thingy..
    }
});
```

Web Service Stuff:

```
[WebMethod]
public string SavePersonById(string ID)
    {
    //do some code here..
    dbContext.Save(ID,"Firstname","Lastnmae");
    return "Successfully Saved!";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#button').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "appWebservices/select.asmx/checkLogin",
            data: "{ ID:'" + $(this).val()+ "'}",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            datatype: "json"
         });
     });
});
```

Write Web services as follow:

```
[WebMethod]
public string checkLogin(string ID)
{
    //Write your code here..
    //return value
}
```

[know moredetails](http://techno-solution.in)